# How to add an overlay with opacity to a video in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

I am new to ffmpeg and am trying to add an overlay on my video. The overlay is scaled to video's size but the problem is that i need to add opacity. Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -ac 2 output.mp4
```

Comment: Transparency or opacity i.e. do you wish to reduce existing transparency?

Comment: I need to increase the transparency of the overlay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the colorchannelmixer filter to set transparency.

`ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[i]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.65[i];[m][i]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -ac 2 output.mp4`

The filter sets the image opacity to 65%

Comment: Thank you but it does not work. I have tried setting opacity to different value but nothing works. I cannot see through the image.

Comment: What opacity value did you try?

Comment: I tried .65, .25, .95. But the result is same for every value.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share full report.

Comment: I tried setting transparency to image manually and now its working fine. Thank You